# Differences between CPL and PPL theories

Tags: ppl, easa, cpl

I am learning now for EASA PPL exams in Czech.
I tried to find some question bank applications, and I found AviationExam app which looks very good.
the problem is that there is no PPL section in AviationExam, only CPL or ATPL.

How much CPL theory is harder than PPL theory ? Can I just use the CPL questions to prepare for PPL? or the theory is much harder ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've solved this by now, but for EASA PPL there are the following options:

If it's Austro Control based question bank , https://aircademy.com/en/ecqb-ppl/ (look for ECQB-PPL TRAINING QUESTIONS download link below)

If it's the UK based Question Bank, then I've heard good things about https://www.airquiz.com/

Good Luck!